# Dynamic color for date in PHP

Tags: php

```
       [![How the page look like][1]][1]    
      <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="Well_CAT" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead> <th>Client_Contract_Number</th>
      <th>Currently_Using</th>
      <th>MBPS_EAM_Number_RIGT</th>
      <th>Model_and_Type</th>
      <th>LFour_Yearly</th>
      <th>Six_Monthly</th>
      <th>One_Yearly</th>
      <th>One_and_Half_Yearly</th>
      <th>Two_Yearly</th>
      <th>Two_and_Half_Yearly</th>
      <th>Three_Yearly</th>
      <th>Three_and_Half_Yearly</th>
      <th>Four_Yearly</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
    </thead>
    <?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
      <tr>
       <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Client_Contract_Number']; ?></td>
       <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Currently_Using']; ?></td>
       <td><? echo $rows['MBPS_EAM_Number_RIGT']; ?></td>
       <td><? echo $rows['Model_and_Type']; ?></td>
       <td><? echo $rows['LFour_Yearly']; ?></td>
       <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['Six_Monthly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['Six_Monthly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['One_Yearly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['One_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['One_and_Half_Yearly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['One_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['Two_Yearly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['Two_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['Two_and_Half_Yearly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['Two_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['Three_Yearly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['Three_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['Three_and_Half_Yearly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['Three_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['Four_Yearly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['Four_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Remarks']; ?></td>
       </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      </table>
      </div>
```

I have asked this question before also, but i need to color code my table on
condition: - 1 - If the date is less than or equal to Today, then background color of the cell = "Red"
condition: - 2 - If the date is greater than today, then background color of the cell = "Green"
condition: - 3 - If the date is 30+today, then background color = "Yellow".

Apart from that, now my table is overlapping the size of my page, i need everything to be shown in the same page without scrolling. 
Please help...

i have done this

```
    <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() >
 new DateTime($rows['Six_Monthly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['Six_Monthly']; ?>
</td>
 <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() >
 new DateTime($rows['One_Yearly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['One_Yearly']; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Welcome. I don't see any color/date related code in there, have you already started coding this?

Comment: where is date column?

Comment: I have done this - <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['Six_Monthly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['Six_Monthly']; ?></td>
         <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() > new DateTime($rows['One_Yearly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['One_Yearly']; ?></td>

Comment: @BilalAhmed <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Six_Monthly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['One_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['One_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Two_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Two_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Three_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Three_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Four_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Remarks']; ?></td>

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the relevant code there, and not in the comments. Thanks

Comment: @kerbholz - Edited with my current code

Comment: @AbcAeffchen - No it is not the same question...

Comment: What's your attempt ?

Comment: @msg - <td class="exdate" style="background-color:<?php echo (new DateTime() >
 new DateTime($rows['Six_Monthly'])) ? 'red' : 'green'; ?>;" ><? echo $rows['Six_Monthly']; ?>
</td>

Comment: Can you explain where exactly the problem is? You have some code written, and that looks fine. Have you checked whether the data you use to construct a `DateTime` object is in the proper format? Additionally, mixing PHP and HTML in such a manner is highly discouraged - try to seperate the logic from the view, this helps getting a better structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of applying background color add specific class according to your condition

```
//css 
<style type="text/css">
   .red-bg{
      background-color: red;
    }
    .green-bg{
      background-color: green;
    }
</style>

//while loop code

<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
      <tr>
       <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Client_Contract_Number']; ?></td>
       <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Currently_Using']; ?></td>
       <td><? echo $rows['MBPS_EAM_Number_RIGT']; ?></td>
       <td><? echo $rows['Model_and_Type']; ?></td>
       <td><? echo $rows['LFour_Yearly']; ?></td>
       <?php 
          $currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
          $newDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate." +30 days"));
        if($currentDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Six_Monthly']))) 
          $Six_Monthly = 'red-bg';
        else if($currentDate < date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Six_Monthly'])) && $newDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Six_Monthly'])))
          $Six_Monthly = 'green-bg';
        else
          $Six_Monthly = 'yellow-bg'; 

        if($currentDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['One_Yearly']))) 
          $One_Yearly = 'red-bg';
        else if($currentDate < date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['One_Yearly'])) && $newDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['One_Yearly'])))
          $One_Yearly = 'green-bg'; 
        else
          $One_Yearly = 'yellow-bg'; 

        if($currentDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['One_and_Half_Yearly']))) 
          $One_and_Half_Yearly = 'red-bg';
        else if($currentDate < date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['One_and_Half_Yearly'])) && $newDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['One_and_Half_Yearly'])))
          $One_and_Half_Yearly = 'green-bg'; 
        else
          $One_and_Half_Yearly = 'yellow-bg'; 

        if($currentDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Two_Yearly']))) 
          $Two_Yearly = 'red-bg';
        else if($currentDate < date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Two_Yearly'])) && $newDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Two_Yearly'])))
          $Two_Yearly = 'green-bg';
        else
          $Two_Yearly = 'yellow-bg';

        if($currentDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Two_and_Half_Yearly']))) 
          $Two_and_Half_Yearly = 'red-bg';
        else if($currentDate < date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Two_and_Half_Yearly'])) && $newDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Two_and_Half_Yearly'])))
          $Two_and_Half_Yearly = 'green-bg';
        else
          $Two_and_Half_Yearly = 'yellow-bg';

        if($currentDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Three_Yearly']))) 
          $Three_Yearly = 'red-bg';
        else if($currentDate < date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Three_Yearly'])) && $newDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Three_Yearly'])))
          $Three_Yearly = 'green-bg';
        else
          $Three_Yearly = 'yellow-bg';

        if($currentDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Three_and_Half_Yearly']))) 
          $Three_and_Half_Yearly = 'red-bg';
        else if($currentDate < date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Three_and_Half_Yearly'])) && $newDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Three_and_Half_Yearly'])))
          $Three_and_Half_Yearly = 'green-bg';
        else
          $Three_and_Half_Yearly = 'yellow-bg';

        if($currentDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Four_Yearly']))) 
          $Four_Yearly = 'red-bg';
        else if($currentDate < date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Four_Yearly'])) && $newDate > date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['Four_Yearly'])))
          $Four_Yearly = 'green-bg'; 
        else
          $Four_Yearly = 'yellow-bg'; 

        ?>
       <td class="exdate <? echo $Six_Monthly; ?>" ><? echo $rows['Six_Monthly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate <? echo $One_Yearly; ?>" ><? echo $rows['One_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate <? echo $One_and_Half_Yearly; ?>" ><? echo $rows['One_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate <? echo $Two_Yearly; ?>" ><? echo $rows['Two_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate <? echo $Two_and_Half_Yearly; ?>" ><? echo $rows['Two_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate <? echo $Three_Yearly; ?>" ><? echo $rows['Three_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate <? echo $Three_and_Half_Yearly; ?>" ><? echo $rows['Three_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate <? echo $Four_Yearly; ?>" ><? echo $rows['Four_Yearly']; ?></td>
        <td class="exdate "><? echo $rows['Remarks']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I have added one pic of my conditional formatting window from MY Ms access database.